# Adding a collection, loop needed?

Tags: entity-framework

I have this code:

```
Schedule s = _entities.Schedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleID == schedule.ScheduleID && x.BookingObject.BookingObjectID == bookingObjectID).FirstOrDefault();

if(s == null)
    s = new Schedule();

s.ScheduleStart = schedule.ScheduleStart;
s.ScheduleEnd = schedule.ScheduleEnd;

foreach (var t in schedule.Timetables)
{   
    s.Timetables.Add(t);
}

_entities.AddToSchedules(s);

_entities.SaveChanges();
```

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

the object schedule gets passed in as a parameter

EDIT:

changed to:

```
  Schedule sh = new Schedule();


  sh.ScheduleStart = schedule.ScheduleStart;
  sh.ScheduleEnd = schedule.ScheduleEnd;

  foreach (var t in schedule.Timetables)
  {
       //sh.Timetables.Add(t);  // doesn't work
        sh.Timetables.Add(new Timetable { DayOfWeek = t.DayOfWeek, StartTime = t.StartTime, EndTime = t.EndTime });   // works
  }

  _entities.AddToSchedules(sh);

  _entities.SaveChanges();
```

is there some logical reason why sh.Timetables.Add(t)  doesn't work since its a collection of Timetable?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Just confirmed that this is likely to be the reason. And created a new [tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/12/02/tip-47-how-fix-up-can-make-it-hard-to-change-relationships.aspx) in [my tips series](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx) to explain.

I can think of one possible reason.Is the relationship between `schedule.Timetables` one to many? I.e. Can a timetable only be assigned to one schedule at a time?

If so, this is failing:

```
  foreach (var t in schedule.Timetables)  {       
     sh.Timetables.Add(t); 
  }
```

Because as you add the 't' to a different schedule, it is automatically removed from the old `schedule.Timetables` collection, which of course modifies the collection you are enumerating, which is a no-no.

If so, the solution is simply to do something like this:

```
  var timetables = schedule.Timetables.ToArray();
  foreach (var t in timetables)  {       
     sh.Timetables.Add(t); 
  }
```

Here you enumerate the collection, before you start modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var time in schedule.Timetables){
     s.Timetables.Add(time)
}
```

You can loop over the time tables in schedule.Timetables and add them to your new entity.

Comment: sadly I get an error (swedish one), something about value has been modified and it cant loop through them

Comment: Are you getting an InvalidOperationException in foreach because the source collection was modified? If so, make sure you aren't trying to add elements of schedule.Timetables to itself (as opposed to adding them to s.Timetables)

Comment: updated my post. And I get that exception. Not sure why though, its the newly created object I want to save to dateabase so

Comment: molgan - I'm pretty sure it's because of EF automatic fixup modifying the collection under the hood. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
s.Timetables.Add(schedule.Timetables)
```

if this isn't the case, it's likely your question needs more information. What is s.Timetables, schedule.Timetables? (types)

Comment: schedule.Timetables is a Entitycollection<Timetable> and I can't seem to add more than 1 if I put s.Timetables.Add. "cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<BookingSystem.Data.Models.Timetable>' to 'BookingSystem.Data.Models.Timetable'"

Comment: Add() takes a base object, not a collection. Iterate through the source collection with foreach, and Add() each object to the destination collection.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be:

```
((List<TimeTable>)s.Timetables).AddRange(((List<TimeTable>)schedule.Timetables));
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first few lines:

```
Schedule s = _entities.Schedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleID == schedule.ScheduleID && x.BookingObject.BookingObjectID == bookingObjectID).FirstOrDefault();

if(s == null)
    s = new Schedule();
```

On the first line, you're querying the database for an object with the same ScheduleID as `schedule` and storing the returned reference in `s`. Assuming that object is available in the database, you're effectively pointing `s` at the same object as `schedule`. That means `s.Timetables` and `schedule.Timetables` are the same collection, which will cause the exception you're getting during the foreach.

I assume you only want to clone the object pointed to by schedule and insert it into the database *if it is not already in the database*. In that case:

```
Schedule s = _entities.Schedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleID == schedule.ScheduleID && x.BookingObject.BookingObjectID == bookingObjectID).FirstOrDefault();

if(s == null)
{
    s = new Schedule();

    s.ScheduleStart = schedule.ScheduleStart;
    s.ScheduleEnd = schedule.ScheduleEnd;

    foreach (var t in schedule.Timetables)
    {   
        s.Timetables.Add(t);
    }

    _entities.AddToSchedules(s);

    _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: changed but I get same exception still.

Comment: when you debug and step through, do you see anything informative happening?